# Solve warning - Setting rounding mode not available

Tags: scip

I compiled FiberSCIP using Cygwin with ZLIB and ZIMPL and just tested the example problem (ug_folder)/check/instances/MINLP/ex1266.mps, but I get many times the same error before solving, wich are:

```
[src/scip/intervalarith.c:192] ERROR: setting rounding mode not available - interval arithmetic is invalid!
```

My command in Cygwin is:

```
./fiberscip fiberscip.set ../check/instances/MINLP/ex1266.mps
```

Is there any setting in the .set file that I can change in order to solve this problem? I didn't find much information about which parameters I am able to set in this kind of file, besides what is said in the README file and what is written in the example settings files. Did I compile UG wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In make/make.cygwin.x86_64.gnu.opt of SCIP, try enabling the -DROUNDING_FE flag in the first line (FLAGS). If that doesn't work, try -DROUNDING_MS instead.